# How to solve " 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'fetcha11' "?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Running the following code

```
import sqlite3
from time import time

#Creation of connection
con=sqlite3.connect('hospitaldb')#creates a db named hospital

with con:
    #create cursor
    cur=con.cursor()
    
    #creation of tables
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTs patient_details(id int,first_name text,last_name text,age int,disease text)")
    
    #to check the number of tables in database hospitaldb
    cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
    print(cur.fetcha11())
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)

#insert records in patient_details
try:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO patient_details VALUES (1,'ab','cd',45,'heart Attack')")

except:
    print("record exists")
```

produces the following error:

> 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'fetcha11'

Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the tour and read [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Could it be that this is a simple typo: `fetcha11()` instead of `fetchall()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: `fetcha11` vs [`fetchall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall). One is using the number one, the other is the letter L. Perhaps you're using a font which does not distinguish between them well.

Comment: thanks, buddy! I did not realize there was a typo.